# Dll from python module is not released in Eclipse / PyDev

Tags: python, unit-testing, dll, pydev

I'm unit-testing a python c module in Eclipse using PyDev unit-testing.
The development steps are: 
I first write the python tests in Eclipse and then the c code that passes
the tests for the module in Codeblocks. Here is where a script is called
to create a dll and ctypes bindings for it. After that the  “dll” and the
“py” code is copied to a directory where the module can be easily imported.
But sometimes I get the error:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\...\pyCModule.dll'

I’ve haven’t found the reason for that (deactivating code analysis and code
completion haven’t helped). I’ve checked with the Process Explorer (from
sysinternals) and it shows that the eclipse process has python.exe as child
(I suppose that’s from PyDev) and that one is using my pyCModule.dll (and
not always releasing it).

Does someone have and idea of want could be done here? or what is wrong?

Thanks in advance !

Francis

Answer (score 2):

This happens because PyDev launches a shell that imports that dll (to do code-completion). You can do Ctrl+2 kill (with focus in a PyDev editor), to kill all the shells that PyDev may have spawned (that way you can update it).

Cheers,

Fabio